# express.js - req.body?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to js, 
I see this a lot in the code I'm reading

```
_.pick(req.body, ' ' , ' ')
```

What does req.body do? 
And when can I say req.body.something?

Comment: You can add more details to your question please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/node-js-extracting-post-data

Answer (score 33):

`req.body` holds parameters that are sent up from the client as part of a POST request. See the [API](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body).

```
// POST user[name]=tobi&user[email]=tobi@learnboost.com
req.body.user.name
// => "tobi"

req.body.user.email
// => "tobi@learnboost.com"

// POST { "name": "tobi" }
req.body.name
// => "tobi"
```

Comment: What happens if something is sent from the server instead of the client and how do you reconcile the two when you get some request from the client and the others from the server?

Answer (score 2):

```
(req.body, ' ' , ' ') --> here req is the parameter of your function and using this parameter your can access the properties over then url.
so look this example
suppose this is form 
<form>
enter the name : <input type="text" name="name">
<button type ="submit"> submit </button> 
</form>

so if you want to access the name -- which is filled by the user end.
so for this you can 
do like this->   console.log(req.body.name);  -- this will print the name (property) in console.
```